# What are examples of memory barriers in C++?

Tags: c++, atomic, memory-barriers

I see C++11 mutexes lock is not `void lock() volatile`. How does the compiler know which functions are memory barriers and which are not? Are all functions barriers even if they are not volatile? What are some less known memory barriers and memory barriers everyone should know?

Comment: It really depends on the platform.  C++ compilers for embedded systems with only a single core may be able to implement mutexes without any sort of memory barrier, because memory is always coherent.

Comment: @BenVoigt, they still need to block compiler instruction reordering.

Answer (score 5):

The runtime library has to implement a mutex in a way so that the compiler knows! The language standard doesn't say anything about how to do this.

Likely, it involves a call to some operating system service that works as a memory barrier. Or the compiler can have an extension, like [void _ReadWriteBarrier();](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f20w0x5e.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

The actual implementation of your `std::mutex` will be such that the compiler doesn't perform illegal reordering, doesn't elide variable loads, and it will ensure that the lock variable is accessed atomically and that the CPU performs the necessary memory barriers for lock acquisition and release.

The details of how much work needs to be done to ensure this vary from platform to platform, but your library implementation will Do The Right Thing.

Comment: My question is more of how does the compiler know whats in mutex and why doesnt it reorder variables before and after the lock? The functions are certainly not marked as volatile. Also i once looked at MSVC headers and it appears that it isnt a template and is linked via lib. So... i don't believe its inlined for the compiler to analyses and see if it requires vars in *this* function not to be reordered...

Comment: @acidzombie24: Presumably, an external function call will never be reordered by the compiler, since as you observe this can never be proven to be correct.